# How to have config parameter in axios post request with headers required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, axios

I was trying to send a post request using axios in my react code which needed both 
'headers parameter' and 'config parameter' at the same time. I found out that there is two types for writing post requests in axios:

1. axios.post(url, data, config)
2. axios({
       url :url,
       method: 'post',
       headers: headers,
       data: data
   })

In type 1 we can't send headers parameter and in type 2 we can't send config parameter.

So is there any way to solve this problem?

> I solved it using xml httpRequest instead of axios, but I'm curious about the way we could solve it using axios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your assumption is wrong you can set the headers in the request config

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

```
{
   headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

base on [doc](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1)

you can set **header** in **config** !

```
axios.post(url, data, {headers : {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'} })
```

or you can send all options as a object

```
axios.request ({
    url: '/user',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        firstName: 'Fred'
    },
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},

    // ... and other options 
})
```